# Forbidden 403 Error .ini files

Tags: php, ini, http-status-code-403

I get a 403 Forbidden error trying to load any .ini file from my Hosting provider.

I found a site where the .ini files actually load [here](http://thaisatellite.tv/ftv/guides.ini)

How can I fix my site to actually load? PHP.ini? htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly Web server has `Allow directory browsing` set `OFF`. You should check first that your ini file location can be accessible or not. Then check your ini location from browser e.g

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/tesProject/push_servers.ini
```